# Python zfill off by one in regular expression

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a script that uses [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) to add leading zeros to numbers matched from a regular expression in Python 3.

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

string = "7-8"
pattern = re.compile("^(\d+)-(\d+)$")
replacement = "-{}-{}-".format(
    "\\1".zfill(2),
    "\\2".zfill(3)
)
result = re.sub(pattern, replacement, string)
print(result)
```

The output I expect is for the first number to be padded to two characters in width and the second number to be padded out to three characters. For example:

```
-07-008-
```

Instead, I'm getting:

```
-7-08-
```

Why is there one less zero than expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're *zfilling* the constants used for your back-reference which are two characters already (`\` and an int), leaving no space for an extra zero for the first character, and just one space for the second character.

You can instead pass a function as your replacement to `re.sub` and do the *zfilling* in there:

```
def repl_fn(m):
  return f'-{m.group(1).zfill(2)}-{m.group(2).zfill(3)}-'

result = re.sub(pattern, repl_fn, string)
print(result)
# -07-008-
```

The *zfilling* is now done at replacement time, not before, as in your code.

Comment: Yep. This got it. I don't really understand why I was getting the value from the back-reference (e.g. `7`) without the zfill. I understand what you're saying about the character count of the back-reference, but if that's what was being operated on, I'd have expected the value to show up as the back-reference string itself (e.g. `\\1` or `\1`). Clearly that's not the case. While I still haven't wrapped my head around why my code doesn't work, I appreciate that your code does. Thanks!

Comment: @AlanW.Smith `"\\2".zfill(3)` is called at the point where the string formatting is executed. `replacement` already has a value `'-\\1-0\\2-'` before reaching `re.sub`.

Comment: Ahhhh. Got it. Thanks again!